# How to search user id and replace name in shell script Linux

Tags: linux, shell

For example A = UserID

user.txt content

```
A1:Alex:Password1
A2:John:Password2
```

Search A2 User ID and Replace John username as Alexander

```
echo -n "Enter user id: "
read userID
```

After i enter the user id, i need to search in user.txt, after found the user id
Enter the replace name John.

Could people please help with how to do it. I tried a few executing instructions, but didn't work.
How can i do it in Shell Script Linux ? Thanks

Thanks for helping
I found the way how to do it from answer.

```
echo -n "Enter user id: "
read userID
echo -n "Enter user name: "
read userName

sed -i 's/'$userID':\w*/'$userID':'$userName'/g' user.txt
```

Comment: This is a simple `sed` command, using `$A` in the address expression of a `s///` command.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your bash script `sed` command as follow

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter user id: "
read userID

sed -i 's/A2:\w*:/A2:'$userID':/g' user.txt
```

It will change in-place `user.txt` file

Comment: I'm new to linux, thanks for your help :)
I think you misunderstood my problem, but never mind, I learned from your answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another simple method is using `awk`. You can pass the userID and replacement name from the shell to `awk` and then locate the record where the first field (`$1`) matches the userID and replace the name (3rd field `$3`) with the new one.

```sh
awk -v id="A2" -v nm="Alexander" -v OFS=":" -F: '$1==id {$3=nm}1' user.txt
```

The strings (or shell variables) are made `awk` variables through the `-v=value` parameters where `id` and `nm` are used to hold the userID and name as `awk` variables. `-v OFS=":"` sets the `awk` Output Field Separator to `":"` so that after the records is modified with the new name, the `":"` are replaced as separators. The `-F:` tells `awk` to use `":"` as the Field Separator to separate the record (line) into fields. The `1` at the end is just shorthand for the default operation `print` to output the records.

**Example Use/Output**

Using a heredoc to supply your input you can do:

```
$ awk -v id="A2" -v nm="Alexander" -v OFS=":" -F: '$1==id {$3=nm}1' << eof
> A1:Alex:Password1
> A2:John:Password2
> eof
A1:Alex:Password1
A2:John:Alexander
```

Comment: Hi Sir, I tried your method and it shows a change in command line since use 1 to print the record but no change in my txt. document. May i know what problem is it? Thanks Sir

Comment: Yes, you are correct. To edit-in-place -- `sed` is the tool. You can do the same with `awk` but you need an intervening temporary file, e.g. `awk ... file > tmp && mv -f tmp file` The edit-in-place is one area where `sed` provides a standard feature `awk` doesn't.